# failed to find 'com.firebase:firebase-ui:0.2.0' in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use **firebase UI** in my android app, but it constantly give build error while adding dependency in `android studio
i tried the tutorial at https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#using-the-library-in-your-android-app and
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-08-27-firebaseui-makes-mobile-easy.html
But both gives me same error

here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "re.book.bookify"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
  compile 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.1.2'
  compile 'com.github.shell-software:viewmover:1.1.0'
  compile 'com.github.shell-software:uitools:1.1.0'
  compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1+'
  compile 'com.firebase:firebase-ui:0.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Where did you add `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-ui:0.2.0'` ? In the build.gradle file ?

Comment: yes in build.gradle file under dependencies

Comment: @PraffulGupta okay .Then show your `build.gradle`

Comment: The 0.2 version of FirebaseUI was published in the `com.firebaseui` group. So the gradle link for it is `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.0'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please post your **build.gradle** First

Add the following lines to the dependencies object at the bottom:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.0'
```

Check This Instructions

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#using-the-library-in-your-android-app

Comment: I have followed the same instructions and its getting connected to firebase database, but not able to use firebase ui

Comment: its works After including the second library.. Thanks@intellij Amiya

Comment: @sudharsanchandrasekaran glad to hear .Move ahead

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Frank van Puffelen, that was the exact problem.
The gradle link given at   https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-08-27-firebaseui-makes-mobile-easy.html is not correct, 
The 0.2 version of FirebaseUI was published in the com.firebaseui group. So the gradle link for it is `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.0'`

Comment: You might want to accept @IntelliJAmiya s answer, since that is the same solution. I just provided some context.